# Valgrind is reporting the Impossible happened using an fexecve call

Tags: c, exec, valgrind

I have a program that loads a simple hello world binary into memory using `memfd_create` and then writing the binary data to the file with `write`. I then fork a process and call `fexecve`.

The code works just fine and I get the usual "hello world" output that I am expecting when I run the program so I went and tested it with Valgrind to make sure there were no memory leaks as it's part of a larger project and got the following Valgrind output:

```
VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting.

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
    Killed by fatal signal

at 0x495B178: fexecve
```

And no output from the hello_world program at all.

I've tried different exec-like functions that work on anonymous files such as `fexecve(file_fd, argv, envp)` and `execveat(file_fd, "", argv, envp, AT_EMPTY_PATH)` and all result in the same Valgrind segfault, but work properly without.

What's even more interesting though is that Valgrind chugs along happily if I use the classic `execve("/path/to/hello_world", argv, envp)`. It reports no memory leaks and that the impossible did not, in fact, occur.

I am running valgrind 3.18.1 on an Ubuntu 22.04.3 vm.

Comment: This sounds like a valgrind bug to me.

Comment: Which version of Valgrind? OS? Architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the same thing as an issue I fixed last April. Try a more recent Valgrind.

```
commit 5f83395616befb96af66ec2cc7f4330605271faf
Author: Paul Floyd <redacted>
Date:   Sun Apr 10 20:55:28 2022 +0200

    Fix a crash handling fexecve.
    
    Found this by testing the Solaris execx (the bits that are
    Linux-compatible) test. That was giving
    
    --28286-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
    --28286-- si_code=2;  Faulting address: 0x4A0095A;  sp: 0x1002ca9c88
    
    valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
       Killed by fatal signal
    
    host stacktrace:
    ==28286==    at 0x5803DE54: vgPlain_strcpy (m_libcbase.c:309)
    ==28286==    by 0x5810A9B3: vgSysWrap_linux_sys_execveat_before (syswrap-linux.c:13310)
    ==28286==    by 0x580953C9: vgPlain_client_syscall (syswrap-main.c:2234)
    
    It's a mistake to copy the path obtained with VG_(resolve_filename) to
    the client ARG2, it's unlikely to have space for the path.
    
    Instead just copy the pointer.
```